# How to get Authentication inside UserDetailsService subclass

Tags: spring, spring-security

I was using custom auth like this

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException{   
     LoggedInUser user = new LoggedInUser();
     ...
     ...
     return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, authentication.getCredentials());
 }
```

here i was setting some value to `authentication` object

Now i am using `password-encoder` so my custom authentication is

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    static final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
}
```

Here inside `loadUserByUsername` how can i set anything to `Authentication` object ?

Answer (score 0):

`UserDetailsService` implementations should be responsible for retrieving user details based on provided ID and not to manipulate `Authentication`. To process a specific `Authentication` object, implement custom `AuthenticationProvider` or extend an existing one (e.g. `DaoAuthenticationProvider`) that will delegate to your `UserDetailsService` to retrieve a user. Such a user can be then assigned to the authentication object and returned from `AuthenticationProvider.authenticate(...)` method.

Look at Spring Security's `DaoAuthenticationProvider` that is implemented this way applying the [single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principles.